# Send Nested Multipart/FormData with Blob via axios post

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm not able to create a nested formData().

My goal is to get:

```
array:3 [
  "table" => "food"
  "id" => "1"
  "media" => array:2 [
     0 => array:1 [
        "url" => "https://picsum.photos/400/400"
         ]
     1 => array:1 [
        "image" => UploadedFile { ... }
         ]
   ]
]
```

I tried to use the package: "object-to-formdata", but it just doesn't like to work I get:

```
array:3 [
  "table" => "food"
  "id" => "1"
  "media" => array:2 [
     0 => array:1 [
        "url" => "https://picsum.photos/400/400"
        "image" => UploadedFile {#593} //it should be in 1 =>
         ]
   ]
]
```

And I cannot use

```
media.append('media[]', {url: "https://picsum.photos/400/400"});
```

It cannot read the file and I get something like that [Object Object]

The object that I want to send is pretty simple build:

```
let obj = {
   table: 'food',
   id: this.food.id,
   media: [
         {url: "https://picsum.photos/400/400"},
         {image: Blob},
         {url: "https://picsum.photos/200/400"},
         ....
      ]
};
```